# Do constants stay the same for ALL users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a web app that I built. It communicates with the Salesforce API. I have users and administrators. All connections to the API use the same credentials.

I am concerned that my API connection is going to be created multiple times because each admin that is logged in has their own instance of the connection.

If I hold the API connection in a constant, do all other sessions/users have access to that exact connection or do I have to connect for each user, or how can I share one single API connection for ALL users?

Comment: Isn't Salesforce's API just an HTTP API?

Answer (score 0):

A stateless API will never have a persistent connection, so there's no use in holding these in constants. Every HTTP request is a separate TCP connection by definition.

It's only things like database or Websocket connections that persist and if you need to manage those you need a connection pool, not a simple constant. If the connection ever fails it needs to be replaced, and if more than one thread potentially requires it you have to handle acquisition and locking properly.

Create your API connectors as necessary. Unless you have a *measurable* performance problem don't worry about it.

Answer (score -1):

A Ruby constant is like a variable, except that its value is supposed to remain constant for the duration of the program. The Ruby interpreter does not actually enforce the constancy of constants, but it does issue a warning if a program changes the value of a constant.

Reference: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html